# Could not write JSON:Infinite recursion(StackOverflowError)nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:Infinite recursion

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I've developed ***Spring Boot + Spring Data Jpa Rest*** example. I developed below code and giving me below error, with that code even I am not able to launch the Swagger giving me error.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-07-22T15:29:04.487+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.demo.entity.Employee[\"department\"]->com.example.demo.entity.Department$HibernateProxy$muKgohop[\"employees\"])",
    "path": "/employees/findEmployees/john"
}
```

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at Mt.map (immutable.js:4401)
>       at e (utils.js:64)
>       at immutable.js:3016
>       at immutable.js:2699
>       at ft.__iterate (immutable.js:2206)
>       at Mt.__iterate (immutable.js:2698)
>       at r.Lt.r.__iterateUncached (immutable.js:3015)
>       at le (immutable.js:604)
>       at r.J.__iterate (immutable.js:274)
>       at r.forEach (immutable.js:4381)

**Logs:** I can see so many logs like belowm which went into recursion.

```
2019-07-22 20:59:04.484  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@79e70d9e<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1587950423 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.484  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@7c90a614<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@891782616 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.484  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@464e1dc3<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1097620444 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.484  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@61b104db<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1262879325 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.484  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@207b7e8e<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@318222175 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.484  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@59a2dc93<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1365596257 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.485  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@6fb47261<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@718420456 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.485  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@6ca2490<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@205724777 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.485  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@7dbea5c9<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1468691307 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.485  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@32b7b8a9<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@352269292 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.485  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@7edcf3e4<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@442667117 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.485  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@2965a60b<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1042756846 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.485  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@21fdce03<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@764641401 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2019-07-22 20:59:04.485  WARN 21016 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@2e805865<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1442507514 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
```

Employee.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
    private Long employeeId;

    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="STATUS")
    private String status;

    @Column(name="BIRTH_DATE")
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name="PROJECT_ASSOCIATION")
    private Integer projectAssociation;

    @Column(name="GOAL_COUNT")
    private Integer goalCnt;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Department department;
}
```

Department.java

```
@Builder
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Department implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="DEPT_ID")
    private Long departmentId;

    @Column(name="DEPT_NAME")
    private String departmentName;

    @Column(name="DEPT_CODE")
    private String departmentCode;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "department")
    private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>(0);
}
```

RestEndPoint

```
@GetMapping("/findEmployees/{searchValue}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> findEmployees(@PathVariable("searchValue") String searchValue) {
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.searchGlobally(searchValue);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(employees, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: it happens because of your bidirectional association - you have to exclude one of those fields form being serialized to json.

Comment: @michalk - How can we do that?

Comment: You can try setting `@JsonIgnore` on one of your fields in entites. Or create DTO objects for your entities and serialize them. The thing is you should stop hibernate from fetching bidirectional relathionships recursively.

Comment: @michalk - I get error `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.demo.entity.Employee["department"]->com.example.demo.entity.Department$HibernateProxy$4RpjSCNJ["hibernateLazyInitializer"])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I simply added `@JsonIgnore` and it working.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "department")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

also

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private Department department;
```

Comment: Using @JsonIgnore at one side is enough. Also,  you can build unidirectional mapping or use join tables.

Comment: @Cigi - If I use `@JsonIgnore`, then I don't see data is also coming for associated entities. Do you know how we can tackle this?

Comment: I prefer to use join table to avoid that problem.
But, if you wanna continue with @JsonIgnore you may use dto. Therefore, you may write your custom response object to get all the fields you need.

Answer (score 1):

If You want to keep value in JSON response in parent Entity, you can do:

```
//without @JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPT_ID", nullable = false)
private Department department;
```

also

```
//with @JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "department")
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Employee> employees;
```

and also @Override hashCode() method in child Entity without employees value, like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((departmentId == null) ? 0 : departmentId .hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((departmentName == null) ? 0 : departmentName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((departmentCode == null) ? 0 : departmentCode.hashCode());
    return result;
}
```